# How to extract content from multiple webpages?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract certain content (review information) from various review websites.

To begin with. I started extracting content just with one web page. I could able to do achieve it without any issues. I have written a python code in order to achieve the same. However I am not sure how can i use the same python module to extract from multiple websites.

I used the below code for extracting the review for the website initially:

```
from webscraping import download, xpath
D = download.Download()
# download and cache the Google Code webpage
html = D.get('http://code.google.com/p/webscraping')
# use xpath to extract the project title
project_title = xpath.get(html, '//div[@id="pname"]/a/span')
```

Here "html" is a variable containing the HTML  content of the webpage.

I would like to extend this solution more generically, so that i can extract the reviews from any websites.

How can i achieve this?

Please note : I do not want to use web scraping tools. However I want to achieve the same using python programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably should take a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov probably `xpaths` are better for scraping and parsing html pages

Comment: I am unsure what is the problem here. If you want to scrape data from another website, you just request another website content and extract data from it. There is no limit of how many websites you can request in single script. If you want to use one selector to retrieve relevant data from every possible website, then this is delusional request - every website will have its own markup and no generalized solution may exist for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get the job done.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '10'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```